# Word VBA - Insert formfield with predefined text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using

```
Selection.FormFields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:= _
        wdFieldFormTextInput
```

to insert some formfields into a Word document. I've been asked to add some text to each formfield, for instance one need to be with the default text "placement".

Is this possible with Word VBA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Result:

```
Dim fld As FormField
Set fld = Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:= _
        wdFieldFormTextInput)
fld.Result = "placement"
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839761.aspx